# Zakah Calculation on Salary

Tags: zakat

I'm seeking guidance on calculating the obligatory Zakah due on my assets. I'm currently residing in Dubai, and my bank account holds 90k AED. However, this amount has fluctuated over the past year; it was 80k AED last month and 20,000 AED eight months ago and so on. Given these changes, I'm uncertain about the Zakah calculation, especially since the full amount hasn't been in my account for an entire year. Additionally, I already owe 30k AED to some Real Estate company (so these 30k AED will be counted in Zakah?).

To illustrate further, my savings varied throughout the year. For instance, they might have been 10k AED in August 2023, increased with my salary to 25k AED, but after expenses, dropped to 17k AED, eventually reaching 90k AED.

Thanks

Thank you.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. Please note that zakat has two conditions the first is having an amount in possession that is over the nisab, secondly this amount must have been in your possession for a full lunar year. Therefore even some rich scholars as a Laith ibn Sa'ad was said to have never paid Zakat since had his money invested in trades. One economic goal of Islam is having commercial boom and reducing the hoarding of money